# how add in Adroid Studio custom font, which reacts on bold automatically?

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile

I added 3 kind of one font in folder font : regular, bold and light. But the problem is, that my application doesnt react on bold, only takes regular font. How to set this globally?

Comment: What you mean 'reacts'? 
Have you tried to add ```android:textStyle="bold"``` in your xml?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to add font-family like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <font
        android:fontStyle="normal"
        android:fontWeight="400"
        android:font="@font/lobster_regular" />
    <font
        android:fontStyle="italic"
        android:fontWeight="400"
        android:font="@font/lobster_italic" />
</font-family>
```

After this you will be able to use this param on views:

```
android:fontFamily="@font/lobster"
```

from: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml